# Why can't I effectively parallelize my reinforcement learning programs using process based parallelism?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, multiprocessing, hpc, joblib

My objective is to run multiple reinforcement learning programs, using the Stable_Baselines3 library, at the same time. What I notice is that as I increase the number of programs, the iteration speed of the program gradually decreases, which is quite surprising since each program should be running on a different process (core).

Here is my program:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

import gym
# from sbx import SAC
import torch

from stable_baselines3 import SAC
def train():


    env = gym.make("Humanoid-v4")

    model = SAC("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
    model.learn(total_timesteps=7e5, progress_bar=True)

def train_model():

    train()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_of_programs = 1
    Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(train)() for i in range(num_of_programs))
```

`num_of_programs` is used to control the number of programs I am trying to run in parallel.
Here are some statistics -

```
    Number of programs  Iteration speed
1   1   ~102 it/s
2   3   ~60 it/s
3   10  ~ 20 it/s
```

I made sure to request enough resources so that there isn't a resource constraint. This is how I request my resources using slurm - `srun --time=10:00:00 --nodes=1 --cpus-per-task=16 --mem=32G  --partition=gpu --gres=gpu:a100-pcie:1 --pty /usr/bin/bash`

Therefore I have 16 cpus, 32G memory and a 40 GB GPU.

I noticed the same issue when I moved from `stable_baselines3` to `sbx`. While `stable_baselines3` using `torch` as its deep learning library, the latter uses `JAX`.

Comment: So you try to run more processes to speed thing up and see that the processes are getting slower individually? Well, if the learning step of the model use multiple cores, using multiple processes running N threads each on N core will simply causes thread over-subscription and introduce a significant overhead (e.g. due to context switches) not to mention the cores should already be saturated so it should not be faster in the first place. If you use a GPU, then using more processes will generally not saturate more the GPU if it is already properly used. It will make things actually slower.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that using more processes or threads does not make things auto-magically faster when a shared saturated resource is a bottleneck.

Comment: I am a newbie with parallel processing, "Well, if the learning step of the model use multiple cores, using multiple processes running N threads each on N core will simply causes thread over-subscription and introduce a significant overhead (e.g. due to context switches) not to mention the cores should already be saturated so it should not be faster in the first place. " - I don't understand this. Are you saying that a single job might take cores from another job? Isn't it joblib's task to ensure that every job has a specific number of cores?

Comment: "If you use a GPU, then using more processes will generally not saturate more the GPU if it is already properly used. It will make things actually slower." - Sorry, I don't get this at all.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Apologies for the followups. I am really new to this topic and the learning curve for this topic is quite steep.

Comment: Are you trying to run parallel processes on a single GPU? This doesn't work. You can parallelize over CPU because your CPU has multiple cores that work independently. Your GPU can only run one GPU process at a time. If you create parallel jobs on a single GPU, they fight for resources and throttle each other.

Comment: Is there a way I can split a large GPU into chunks. Because I have 10 runs that I need to parallelize. Allocating 10 GPUs is not going to be possible.

Comment: Before you look at this you need to know if the current work is saturating GPU processing power. If it is you gain nothing from running multiple simultaneous instances sharing a GPU (e.g. using MIG). All that will happen is that each instance will go 10x slower and you will have exactly the same time to solution. Do some basic profiling (most ML tools have a profiles Ng interface that shows how well the GPU processing power is being used)

Comment: @AndyT Sure, I will work on using profilers to check that. Rather than MIG (which has a limit of 7 partitions from what I see), can't I use software like pycuda to do multiprocessing over the GPU?

Comment: *"Sorry, I don't get this at all."* A GPU runs parallel kernels. While a kernel may not use all the resources of a GPU, if often do for computationally intensive kernels. Running multiple parallel tasks does not make things faster assuming the GPU was already used at its full capacity with one kernel. This is also what was pointed out by Karl.

Comment: The same thing is true for a CPU. If you run a process with 8 thread on 8 cores which saturate them. Running two processes of 8 threads each will not make things faster.

Comment: If this is still not clear for you, please read more information about how GPUs operate. If you do not know where to start, then note that Wikipedia and the Nvidia developer guide contains a lot of (detailed) information about this (though the later is only for Nvidia GPUs -- which are not so far from AMD/Intel ones from the user point of view of beginners).

Comment: @Karl *"Your GPU can only run one GPU process at a time."* Note that this specific sentence is AFAIK not true on Nvidia GPUs : recent GPUs (probably since Kepler), can partition kernels of multiple processes on different SMs (they can also do context switches too). IDK for AMD though. This assumes that a kernel does not use all the SMs which is not very common.